# How to make a basic HTTP request with API key in Google Translate API v2?

Tags: rest, xmlhttprequest, google-translation-api

I want to make a translation with Google Translate API v2 with a basic HTTP request. I get an API key from the console but I can't find out how to use arguments to make the translation.

Note: I want it to autodetect the source language and I only want to choose the target language.

This is the URL that I tried to use:
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?fields=detections&key=BIzaSyA8uHGnsA8ICcBWWJcxhqVePGFMq0L4u0g&q=grapes&target=es

It returns this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart).

The authentication token goes in the `Authorization` request header, not the query string.

Comment: This is why I'm here. I didn't success with the documentation. I just need a sample example.

Comment: i did a similar thing using the second answer on this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453841/google-cloud-translator-net-client